# Где хранятся роли в базе данных 1C?

Tags: 1с

Я хочу сделать скрипт, который бы получал пользователей и их права в системе постгрес запросом без запуска клиента 1С. В базе данных PostgreSQL нашел таблицу с пользователями и id их профилей. Но как найти таблицу с самими профилями, их ролями и описаниями?

Answer (score 1):

Либо покурить документацию платформы, может там есть описание. Либо использовать обработку в 1С, которая показывает структуру хранимых данных, связывая их с метаданными.

Либо попробовать через [это](https://v8.1c.ru/obuchenie-programmistov/primery-razrabotki/sistemnye_protsedury_i_funktsii/kak_prosmotret_strukturu_tablits_informatsionnoy_bazy.htm) что-то слепить.

Comment: добавлю, см  РегистрСведений.ПраваРолей